# Get values that occur in multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I perform four seperate mysql queries that return four different arrays of userid's. I need to check all the arrays for userid's that occur in all arrays and then create a new array with those values so that I can use that in another query.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [userid] => 11 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [userid] => 22 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [userid] => 33 ) 
      ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [userid] => 11 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [userid] => 99 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [userid] => 33 ) 
      ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [userid] => 11 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [userid] => 33 ) 
      ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [client_id] => 11 )
        [1] => Array ( [client_id] => 33 )
        [2] => Array ( [client_id] => 99 )
      )
```

So my final array, from these four, would be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 11 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 33 ) 
      )
```

I was trying to mickey mouse a solution with `array_count_values` but wasn't having much success with that.

Comment: The last array has `client_id` instead of `userid`. Is that intended?

Comment: And you've tried `array_unique`?

Comment: @Jack yes this is intended

Comment: @njk isnt `array_unqiue` the opposite of what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's built-in array functions can handle most of what you need in just a few lines, without having to resort to a lot of manual looping.

Since you have different keys on those arrays, you can run over each with [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to extract the key you want and flatten it to a single dimension.  Then call [`array_intersect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) over the four resultant arrays to get the intersecting ids:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/x0Ncm0

```
// Your original arrays...
$a1 = array(array('userid'=>11),array('userid'=>22),array('userid'=>33));
$a2 = array(array('userid'=>11),array('userid'=>99),array('userid'=>33));
$a3 = array(array('userid'=>11),array('userid'=>33));
$a4 = array(array('client_id'=>11),array('client_id'=>33),array('client_id'=>99));

// Flatten each array using array_map() to return the desired key
function callback_userid($a) { return $a['userid']; }
function callback_client_id($a) { return $a['client_id']; }

$a1flat = array_map('callback_userid', $a1);
$a2flat = array_map('callback_userid', $a2);
$a3flat = array_map('callback_userid', $a3);
$a4flat = array_map('callback_client_id', $a4);

// Then get an intersection of all four flattened arrays
print_r(array_intersect($a1flat, $a2flat, $a3flat, $a4flat));

Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [2] => 33
)
```

Call `array_values()` on the output array, if you want to re-index the keys from zero. Or if you really need to make a 2D array out of them keyed as `id`, a loop will do:

```
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
  // Append a new array with 'id'
  $output[] = array('id' => $value);
  // unset the original key
  unset($output[$key]);
}
```

It is likely though that if you are not using these four queries for very distinct purposes (and therefore didn't have to execute them individually anyway), that you would be able to coax out this information in a single SQL query.  Hard to say without seeing any more code though.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this in a single query instead of 4-5 separate queries using a union/join with MySQL, but without seeing your database query and design I can't be sure of that. But I'd be willing to bet you could. Try to make the minimal amount of queries as possible, as it slows down performance.

Aside from the following statement above, you could handle this one of a few ways.

The most practical?

Create an empty array say for example called **$user_ids**

Loop through each array and create an index with the user_id from the SQL data within the array $user_ids and append 1 to it's value so it acts as a counter. After you're finished looping through the SQL data, loop through your counter array and unset anything less than the number of arrays your looping through.

**Example:**

```
    $user_ids = array();
    $mysql_dataset = array($first_array, $second_array, $third_array, $fourth_array);

    foreach ($mysql_dataset as $mysql_data) {
            foreach ($mysql_data as $user) {
                    if (empty($user_ids[$user['user_id']])) {
                            $user_ids[$user['user_id']] = 0;
                    }

                    $user_ids[$user['user_id']]++;
            }
    }

    foreach ($user_ids as $user_id => $count) {
            if ($count < 4) {
                    unset($user_ids[$user_id]);
            }
    }

    print_r($user_ids);
```